# What is the _xcode field of the .NET Exception type?

Tags: .net, exception

In my unit tests I need to perform deep equality tests of two objects, which are expected to be identical. During the tests I discover some interesting fields in system types that break my code. `Exception._xcode` is the most recent one. Here are a couple of facts about this field:

1. It is initialized to `-532459699` in all the `Exception` constructors, except the custom deserialization constructor, where it is simply never mentioned (thanks Reflector).
2. It is not marked with the `NonSerialized` attribute.

Given these facts, the field is reset to 0 after an `Exception` object is deserialized, which is certainly different from what it is set to in constructors.

I am wondering what is the raison d'être of this field?

Thanks.

Comment: I have found this to be equally frustrating.  Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

This field is used to store COM+ exception codes and it's value is assigned to the constant `_COMPlusExceptionCode`.

Comment: @Darin, I do not understand something. According to Reflector _COMPlusExceptionCode is a const int. It does not warrant the existence of the _xcode member variable, which looks like just occupying its space for nothing. Please, correct me.