# What's the significance of -532459699?

Tags: .net, exception, magic-numbers

This is a number that's returned as an exit code in many .NET exceptions (particularly COM exceptions, I think).

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935166/what-is-the-xcode-field-of-the-net-exception-type) someone used Reflector to find out that this value was initialized to a private variable in nearly every Exception constructor.

My question is, why? What significance does this number have? It's hard to believe that it was chosen arbitrarily. I don't even see any numeric significance (e.g., in its binary or hex representation).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you pay attention to its hex representation, `E0434F4D`? Here's a brief synopsis:

```
E0 - represents E
43 - ASCII for C
4F - ASCII for O
4D - ASCII for M
```

So it's `ECOM`, or "exception from COM".